# android camera detection

Tags: android, camera

How can I detect programmatically if a phone has a camera ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Android compliant phones have to have a camera installed if they claim to run Android version 1.6 or higher. See http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/de//compatibility/android-1.6-cdd.pdf for the device compatiblity program.

Sadly there's no 1.5 ccd to be found anywhere. I'm however pretty sure that all currently available 1.5 devices do indeed have a camera. For tablets running 1.5 i'd not be that sure.

Answer (score 11):

[`PackageManager#hasSystemFeature(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature(java.lang.String)) - pass [`PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA) as the argument.

Comment: Camera.open() is supported since API 1 and returns null if no camera is available.

`Camera cam = Camera.open();
if(null == cam){
  //no camera exists
}else{
  //camera exists
   cam.release();
}`